# Why can't I move forward / jump in a rtmp stream.dump using mplayer

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, rtmp, mplayer

I often download rtmp videos from techtalks.tv using

```
mplayer -dumpstream rtmpurl
```

When I play the stream in vlc, I cannot move to an arbitrary location - it crashes. Why is this? Can I convert the stream to some other format where I can jump to an arbitrary location like any mp4/mpeg video? How do I do that?

Comment: you are playing the resultant file, is that right? if you play it in mplayer can it seek?

Comment: Yes I'm playing the stream.dump file. It cannot seek in mplayer either.

Comment: you might be able to run mencoder and rebuild the index (http://mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mplayer-users/2004-December/050174.html) or repackage it somehow to a new container format using mencoder or ffmpeg. GL!

Comment: Thanks. It just does 2 mins of conversion and then gives an error about "Too many audio packets in the buffer". I'll ask on the mplayer forums itself.

Comment: ffmpeg -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.avi maybe...